# Scheduled task doesn't run for an app converted by Desktop App Converter

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I have converted one desktop app by using DAC but scheduled task fails. Tasks are created successfully but those fail to run with error 2147942405. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the StartupTask extension in your appxmanifest to declare your scheduled tasks:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions

Comment: I tried but nothing changed. Why should I add startup task for scheduled task?

Comment: The startup task didn't run, or it didn't solve the actual problem? We may need you to go back and add some more details in your questions, regarding what you are trying to accomplish, and how your code currently does it. I was assuming you are asking about auto-launch at startup, but maybe I misinterpreted.

Comment: It sounds to me like he's trying to schedule something for a specific time, as opposed to on-boot.